# How to implement REST class to handle all HTTP methods in a single method

Tags: java, web-services, rest, http-method

I am using jersey implementation of JAX-RS specification, written specific methods to handle each HTTP request types i.e. POST, GET. PUT and DELETE. But I want to know how we can handle all these requests in a single method. May be its a trivial question, please share your thoughts.

Comment: does it make sense ? can you do all the things with your hands only or your each organ does each specific functionality ?

Comment: There are valid cases for this. For instance I'm wring a way for my jersey service to handle requests for a legacy system while migrate to a new API.
I need any case that isn't explicitly handled to be handled by the legacy resources.

Answer (score 1):

First, I do not recommend this as it is *smells* of [NIH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Invented_Here) and is almost certainly going to lead you to unmaintainable code. That being said, in Java we have the [HttpServlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html). From that documentation, emphasis mine -

> There's *almost* **no reason** to override the service method. service handles standard HTTP requests by dispatching them to the handler methods for each HTTP request type (the doXXX methods listed above).

That is precisely what you are asking how to do, so *override* the [service method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnafv.html).